# XSL markup following root not well formed

Tags: xslt, jaxb, marshalling

I have this file that is considered well formed by online checker yet I keep getting an error while trying to marshal it with jaxb.

Here is the error:

> System ID Unknown; Line #1; Column #144;

The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

And here is the used XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:stats="http://aps.edf.fr/xsd/stats"  exclude-result-prefixes="stats">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/stats:Data">
    <COMM>
        <COM_DAT><xsl:value-of select="stats:DateEnvoi"/></COM_DAT>
        <COM_VAR>{COM_VAR}</COM_VAR>
        <COM_LNG>FR</COM_LNG>
        <COM_MARQUE><xsl:value-of select="stats:Flag"/></COM_MARQUE>
        <COD_FIL>{COD_FIL}</COD_FIL>
        <COM_REF><xsl:value-of select="stats:Reference"/></COM_REF>
        <DATA_COM>
            <ENT_EDI>
                <PER type="DEST">
                    <CIV>{Civilite}</CIV>
                    <NOM>{Nom}</NOM>
                </PER>
                <URL_ESP_CLI><xsl:value-of select="stats:UrlEspClient"/></URL_ESP_CLI>
                <NOM_FICH_STAT><xsl:value-of select="stats:NomFichier"/></NOM_FICH_STAT>
            </ENT_EDI>
        </DATA_COM>
    </COMM>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you guys easily see the error?
I've been stuck on this for 2 days now :(

Comment: Are you trying to martial the output from this transform? What does it look like? What does the input file look like?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your XSLT using [xslttest.appspot.com](http://xslttest.appspot.com) and got no error.

From the location of your error (row 1, column 144) I conclude that your XSLT processor is not able to consume the word `exclude-result-prefix`.

Check whether your XSLT processor supports this feature.
Try e.g. to run the transformation without this clause.

Another possibility is an error in your XML file. Actually I'm not sure, to which file relates the error message (XML or XSLT).

E.g. check whether your XML file contains proper *xmlns* specifications.

Pay special attention to row 1, column 144 in your XML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorow. I worked on other things lately but I'll have to finish this during this week. I'll keep you updated.